# How to schedule dags in Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow, frequency, airflow-scheduler, directed-acyclic-graphs

How to schedule a dag/ set a frequency/  in Airflow with the following requirement? looking for some python code or some cron expression to meet the requirement

The dag should run on 7th,14th,21st,28th day for the current month
and for the day 1 of next month, the dag should run for the previous month

Eg., on 7th,14th,21st,28th April the dag should run for April
and on 1st May the dag should run for April

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, I have created the dag in airflow but i want that dag to run on those particular dates with that requirement without any manual intervention. I want to set some frequency or schedule the dags to run on those days to meet the requirement. Is it possible to meet that requirement?